# Meaning of Zabbix user parameter syntax

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I am using `Zabbix agent v2.2.2`.

I have added some user parameters and got them working but I don't understand what codes in their outputs mean. I use normal user parameter syntax. (`UserParameter=<key>,<command>`).

For user parameter that does not work:

```
zabbix_agentd -t user_param_with_error
user_param_with_error                         [m|ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED]
```

One that works (`33` is the expected result of the test.):

```
zabbix_agentd -t user_param
user_param                          [t|33]
```

What do these `t` and `m` characters mean before the actual result?
I have read the Zabbix documentation about user parameters but could not find explanation to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are documented in the [agent daemon manpage](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manpages/zabbix_agentd). Quoting it:

-p, --print
    Print known items and exit. For each item either generic defaults are used, or specific defaults for testing are supplied. These defaults are listed in square brackets as item key parameters. Returned values are enclosed in square brackets and prefixed with the type of the returned value, separated by a pipe character. For user parameters type is always t, as the agent can not determine all possible return values. Items, displayed as working, are not guaranteed to work from the Zabbix server or zabbix_get when querying a running agent daemon as permissions or environment may be different. Returned value types are:

- d
          Number with a decimal part.
- m
          Not supported. This could be caused by querying an item that only works in the active mode like a log monitoring item or an item that requires multiple collected values. Permission issues or incorrect user parameters could also result in the not supported state.
- s
          Text. Maximum length not limited.
- t
          Text. Same as s.
- u
          Unsigned integer.